# Need help on how to write a crawler for Android market

Tags: android, web-crawler

Can someone provide some pointers on how to write a crawler in Java to gather info about apps from android market? because the android market is accessible only from a android device (i.e. not over web).

Thanks!

Comment: First, any crawler should react correctly to robot.txt, and if Google doesn't want this info crawled they will state that in this file, but you could have an Android application crawl through, but I expect there is a reason it isn't accessible over the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a crawler on top of android-market-api and can be found here: 
http://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Will get you started.